# How do I get distinct values on calculated columns using LINQ to SQL?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

I am performing a LINQ to SQL query using Entity Framework (C#) where I need to retrieve only distinct values of a single column. The trouble is, I need to trim some of these columns BEFORE performing the distinct operation. For example:

```
Region
--------------
Primary
Primary Region
Secondary 
Secondary Region
Primary Region
```

Should become:

```
Region
-----------
Primary
Secondary
```

Right now I am achieving this with the following query:

```
IQueryable<Region> regions =
(
    from region in db.Regions
    select new Region
    {
        RegionName = detail.RegionName
    }
).Distinct().OrderBy(r => r.RegionName);

return regions
    .ToArray()
    .Select(r => r.RegionName)
    .ToArray()
    .Distinct()
    .Select(r => new Region { RegionName = r })
    .ToArray();

public class Region
{
    private string _regionName;
    
    public string RegionName 
    { 
        get => _regionName;

        set => _regionName = value?.IndexOf(" Region") > 1 ? value?.Substring(0, value.IndexOf(" Region")) : value;
    }
}
```

The Region class does the job of stripping the name. However this seems terribly inefficient, having to do all of the conversions to arrays and back to Region and back to arrays. Is there a better way?

Comment: Whoa, what's with all the ToArray? Why do you think it's necessary to whack that in all over the place?

Comment: Please clarify. LINQ to SQL and Entity Framework are two competing technologies. I'm suspecting you're using the later here. Also, clarify if you are using EF Core or EF for .Net Framework (4.x)

Answer (score 0):

I guess below would get translated from linq to sql:

```
var distinctRegions = db.Regions
      .Select(c => c.RegionName.Replace(" Region", "").Trim()) //Trim() (just in case) to remove any leading and trailing whitespaces.
      .Distinct()
      .OrderBy(c => c);
```

If this works, it means you need to modify your `Region` class' `RegionName` property to simple `{ get; set; }`

Comment: Trim seems unnecessary here. OP also has OrderBy; recommend you include it or state you excluded it for clarity